# What determines success or failure of SQL Server Job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-agent

I have a query that I want to run in a SQL Server job.  I would like to have the query report success if the query returns 1 or more rows, and to return failure if the query does not reutrn and rows.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

I think you will have to do this within the query:

```
IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No records returned',16,1)
        RETURN
    END
```

If no rows are returned, an error will occur and the job will have a failure status.

Comment: Thank you, Dave.  This would be a step in the job after the query itself executes?

Comment: No, put it in the same step as the query.

Comment: So the command box of the step would look as follows?

SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Year = '2014' AND Month = '08'

IF @@ROWCOUNT < 1
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('No records returned',16,1)
        RETURN
    END

Comment: That looks correct to me.  How is it working for you?

Comment: I have an unrelated question.  When it sends out the failure email, I use an Operator in SQL.  How do I modify the message in that email?

Answer (score 0):

Have a step that checks the count and calls RAISERROR or THROWs if there are no rows.